# Consulta PL Sql Postgre - Passar nome da tabela e campo por referência

Tags: postgresql

Preciso de um pl/sql que retorne o valor máximo contido na coluna de uma tabela passando por referência o nome da tabela e o nome do campo.

estou usando assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_post_gera_chave_numerica(var_nm_tabela character varying, var_nm_campo character varying)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    var_sql character varying;
    var_id numeric;
BEGIN
    var_sql:= 'SELECT into var_id max('|| $2 || ') FROM ' || $1;
    execute var_sql;
    RETURN var_id;      
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Chamada:

```
SELECT fn_post_gera_chave_numerica('tblcadlinhacelular', 'ccodigo');
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode formatar sua *query* dinâmicamente usando a função de formatação de strings [FORMAT()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) para então executá-la por meio do comando  [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Sua função poderia ser reescrita da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_post_gera_chave_numerica(_tabela TEXT, _coluna TEXT)
RETURNS BIGINT AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    _max BIGINT;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT max(%s) FROM %s;', _coluna, _tabela) INTO _max;
    RETURN _max;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Funcionou.. valeuuu.. adicionei... EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT COALESCE(max(%s), 0) FROM %s;', _coluna, _tabela) INTO _max;